# How get header of email using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, ntlm

I have email  function in codeigniter like this

```
            $this->email->attach('file.txt');
            $this->email->from('messi6@barcelona.com', 'leo messi');
            $this->email->to("messifan@gmail.com"); 
            $this->email->subject('Messi fan');
            $msg = $this->load->view('messi_the_best','',TRUE);
            $this->email->message($msg);    
            $this->email->send();
```

This is working fine.Now i moved this to new server(both mail server and web server).my new mail server only support **ntlm authentication**. so codeigniter email class not support **ntlm authentication**. so i added [this](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/31.html) class to library. but this class not support attach file.  Now  i want to get header part of email from codeigniter email class. and pass this header of email to my new class to send email.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by extending CodeIgniters Email class

```
<?php

class MY_Email extends CI_Email{

  public function get_header_str()
  {
    return $this->_header_str;
  }

}

?>
```